# initial data load for Grails 2 app

Tags: grails

I'm trying to implement initial data load functionality form a tab delimited text file and wonder what's the best/recommended place for placing such a file. My initial thought would be to put it in a place like /WEB-INF/data-load, but then how do I access that from the Bootstrap.grooy ?? Or should I read it in from /MyWebApp/data-load/ directory?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.... finally figured it out. Here's what happens in the Bootstrap.groovy

```
class BootStrap {

    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

    /* stuff omitted for brevity */

        if( Information.count < 1 ) {
            dataLoadService.loadInformation( 
                 grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource( '/WEB-INF/data-load/Information.tsv').file )
        }
```

... that simple :-)

Answer (score 0):

you may want to do that in some environments:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
        environments {
            production {
            }
            development { loadSomeData() }
            test {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ... very true. That's the easy part now ;-)